# How to insert/update of Change Feed to cosmos GraphDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am new to this cosmos Graph API.

Here My use case is.

1. get the change feed document of cosmosDB SQL and parse the document such way that to insert/update to cosmos GraphDB.

I tried spark change feed connector. It's working cosmos DB SQL to cosmos SQL Db.

I have implemented for each writer of write stream.

I am using apache tinkerpop gremlin query.

Not able to connect tinkerpop connection in spark with scala.

Any suggestions/code snippets much appreciated.

One more question:

is spark change feed connector support java version of spark structured streaming?